# Spring Boot: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query

Tags: spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot and configured my Application like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan
@EntityScan("ch.xy.model")
public class Application {

    @Autowired
    private ImportDAO importDao;

}
```

ImportDAO looks like that:

```
@Repository
public class ImportDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Transactional
    void removeTempoAccounts() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM TempoAccount t WHERE t.manual = false");
        q.executeUpdate();
    }
}
```

But when removeTempoAcconts is executed I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy49.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at ch.post.pf.jira.tempocats.pspimport.ImportDAO.removeTempoAccounts(ImportDAO.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:711)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:644)
    at ch.post.pf.jira.tempocats.pspimport.ImportDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1883cf82.removeTempoAccounts(<generated>)
    at ch.post.pf.jira.tempocats.pspimport.PspImport.run(PspImport.java:32)
    at ch.post.pf.jira.tempocats.pspimport.Application.main(Application.java:20)
```

What's wrong with my configuration?

Comment: Can you try making an interface which `ImportDAO` will implement and let me know what happens?

Comment: Either that or try to add `cglib` to your build file.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
@Transactional
void removeTempoAccounts() {
```

Method had default visibility. Therefore the proxy mechanism was not active!
After changing to public everthing works as expected!

Answer (score 7):

Try to use the @Transactional annotation from Spring package
like `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`
Then it should work